# android is it possible to run a service at background untill we stop it

Tags: android, service

In my application User login logout things are there.
I want once an user login means it ll get updates from server like in form of message.

in every 10sec the server send new messages. 
I want for every user who are logged in they will get all updated meassage from server one by one from server.

When an user click login button the service will start. and logout means service will stop.

i did like this

```
public class MessageService extends Service {

    public String currentMessage="";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        checkForCurrentTimestamp();

    }


    private void checkForCurrentTimestamp() {
        //check TimeSatmp with Server TimeStamp
        //if(!same)
        //currentMessage= get message stored in server

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and within my LoginActivity's loginButton click i write to start the service  and logoutButton click it stop the service.

Is it updating all the messages one by one to every user untill they logged out?

Is this the write way to do?

Answer (score 0):

This will start new instance of service on every login , which will increase battery consumption and decay performance by singificant amount . so implement onBind such that you can use BindService such that returned IBinder can deal with messages from server for its user .

Comment: that means i should use Service only. and instead of writing all these thing in oncreate() i ll write inside onBind? Just clear me

Comment: i am assuming that multiple clients can use your service simultaneousness . so bind with started service is better that start another one .

Comment: to bind service i have to give,     bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
whats the use of mConnection here?